# Why does "(^man)+" match things without "man" at line start?

Tags: regex, apt

If I open a Linux shell that uses an `apt` package management system and execute `apt-cache search --names-only "(^man)+"` why does it match/output things like:

- gman - small man(1) front-end for X
- jed-extra - collection of useful Jed modes and utilities

My nascent understanding of POSIX.2 regex patterns considered the atom (^man) to be something that would only match the string "man" right at the beginning of a line. Clearly, the aforementioned lines do not have "man" at line start. Why were they printed to my terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`man apt-cache`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/apt-cache.8.en.html) says `--names-only` means "Only search on the package and provided package names". Your command will match any package where either the package name or a provided package name starts with `man`, and both `gman` and `jed-extra` have `man-browser` as a provided package name (you can see this with `apt-cache show`).